# Calculus Subway Problem

Tags: calculus, word-problem

> A subway train travels over a distance $s$ in $t$ seconds. It starts from rest (zero velocity) and ends at rest. In the first part of its journey, it moves with constant acceleration $f$ and in the second part with constant deceleration (negative deceleration) $r$. Show that $$s = \frac{\frac{frt^2}{f + r}}{2}$$

I tried doing this multiple times but to no avail. I used $x$ to represent the number of seconds traveled with acceleration $f$ and then $t - x$ to represent the number of seconds decelerating. I'm still not sure how to do it. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The area under the curve equals the distance traveled because integratingis really just adding up every value of the curve. The slope of the left side it $f$ and the slope of the right side is $-r$.
$$s=\mbox{area}=\frac12v_mt$$
Now lets find $v_m$ in terms of $f$ and $r$

Note that the slope is rise over run. $f=\dfrac{v_m}{x}$ and $r=\dfrac{v_m}{t-x}$

So we need to eliminate $x$ and find $v_m$$$x=\frac{v_m}{f},x=t-\frac{v_m}{r}$$$$\frac{v_m}{f}=t-\frac{vM}{r}$$$$rv_m=frt-fv_m$$$$v_m=\frac{fr}{f+r}t$$$$s=\frac12\left[\frac{fr}{f+r}t\right]t$$$$s=\left[\frac{fr}{f+r}\right]\frac{t^2}{2}$$$$s=\frac{\frac{frt^2}{f+r}}{2}$$